# how can I solve str' object does not support item assignmen?

Tags: python, string, button, tkinter, random

Thank you for your prompt reply. I posted it again because I wanted to hear the answer in more detail.
I'm still inexperienced in Python, so I've implemented all nine cases of the Monty Hall dilemma.
It works well until you press a function called "restart." The number of attempts, number of successes, success rates are good, and the number of cases works well without errors.
The first thing I thought about was,
If you press the button "restart!", the images of the three buttons that you first created will be replaced with question marks, and you will try to start over again by assigning random values to each button.
When I first created this program,

```
 [button,button1,button2]=random.shuffle(['car','goat','goat'])
```

And I decided on all nine cases.
for example,

```
if button=='car':
trival=trival+1
def button_funtion():
    global trival
    b=[button2,button3]
    x1,x2=random.sample(b,2)
    x1['image']=goat_image
```

Like this.
Until I made the button "restart," the program worked as I thought.
So if I press the "restart" button, Like

```
def restart():
global button
global button1
global button2
global trival
global count
button['image']=question mark
button1['image']=question mark
button2['image']=question mark
[button,button1,button2]=random.shuffle(['car','goat','goat'])
if button=='car'
    ...
    ...
```

I thought it would work well if I copied and pasted the nine cases that worked well before.
But when you press the button here, you say,

```
 "Str' object does not support item assignment."
```

There was an error.
how can I solve it?

Comment: If `goat` and `car` are variables that hold buttons, don't put them in quotes.

Comment: "how can I solve it?" - please provide more code, ideally a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If `button` is a string as shown in the example, then `button['image']` makes no sense.  I think you've simplified your example too much.

Comment: You're missing a quote in `['goat,'goat','car']` so this code shouldn't run at all.

Comment: Your first posted code is invalid as `random.shuffle()` return `None` and it cannot be unpacked to a list of items.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: error message should show you in which line you have problem and you should check what you have in variables - you can use `print()` to check it.